# What is the percentage of vaishnavite temples that have anya-devata worship?

Tags: temple, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

for example the anantapadmanabhaswamy temple in kerala

http://www.sreepadmanabhaswamytemple.org/pooja.aspx

you can see that worship services for

```
Sree Sastha 

Agrashala Ganapathy
```

are offered.

https://templesinindiainfo.com/adayar-sri-anantha-padmanabha-swamy-temple-time-pooja-and-price-details/

In the chennai temple - which I believe was built by the Kerala temple authorities - the following are offered:

durga parameswari homam
maha ganapathy homam

Note: I'm not asking for names of specific temples, just percentage figures.

Comment: I'm putting your question on hold for the moment, because you're basically asking people to go through all the Vishnu temples in the world and say which ones worship other gods.  If you want to restrict it to a smaller subset, like the Divya Desams, that would be more acceptable.

Comment: I edited the question to ask for any other examples than the ones I cited @keshav srinivasan.

Comment: @SK you have to be careful with way of posting else it could trouble you .

Comment: How many temples is changed to any other temples. What difference did it make? It is still too broad. Plus, you are asking divya desam along with all the temples.

Comment: more: http://www.spiderkerala.net/resources/8196-World-Famous-Sree-Padmanabhaswamy-Temple.aspx  "Another one of the annual festival of importance connected with the Sri Padmanabha is the Navarathri (9 nights) (Dussera) festival. In this festival the idols of the Saraswathi (goddess of learning and consort of lord Brahma), Durga (goddess of sakti – power and consort of the Lord Siva) and Lord Murukan (Sri Subramanian – Karthikeyan, the son of Lord Siva and goddess Parvathy) will be brought to Kuthira Malika (horse palace) in front of the Sri Padmanabhaswamy temple in a procession for Aaratu."

Comment: how is this question different from your question "are there any low-caste vaikhanasa priests" @keshav srinivasan ?  this question has been closed arbitrarily.

Comment: @SK My question was about whether the Vaikhanasa sect allows low-caste people to be priests (to which, incidentally, the answer is no). The problem with your question is that it's too broad.  You would never have a comprehensive answer, instead you'd have a bunch of individual answers listing different temples. Like I said, if you narrowed the Vishnu temples you're asking about to a smaller set, like the 108 Divya Desams or the 8 Swayam Vyakta Kshetras, then it would be more acceptable, because then someone could give an answer listing which temples in the set have Anyadevatas and which don't.

Comment: I suspect vaishnavite sectarianism is also dissolving just like other sectarianisms have more or less disappeared.  I am asking for data to support or refute the conjecture @keshav srinivasan

Comment: I suspect you're right.  Hindu Universalism, which I view as a negative trend, is on the rise.  But you should phrase your question in a way that doesn't just invite indefinite lists of temples in the answers.  One way to do that is to ask "What is the percentage of Vishnu temples with statues of other gods?"  That would be answerable with a statistic rather than an indefinite list.

Comment: I edited the question.  the trend is toward Sri Sri Ravishankar and not the chap who opened a vaishnavite temple in New York @keshav srinivasan

Comment: @SK OK, I edited your question and reopened it.  And yes, I agree that's the trend.  It's the nature of the Kali Yuga.  By the way, you're talking about the Pomona temple, right?

Comment: yes - seems so utterly senseless to me - reminds me of this elderly lady who was getting a new thali for her husband's 80th birthday - she instructed her daughter going to chidambarm - get it blessed by the vishnu idoll ant not the Nataraja!

Comment: @SK It's not senseless at all. It's that after you perform Sharanagati, you're considered "married" to Sriman Narayana, so worshiping other gods is like cheating on your spouse.